# cancelling parts of an equation and equating it to something

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics, amsmath

I want to cancel like in this sample picture I have attached, however using the command `\cancelto{}{}` am not getting what I want. My sample code is shown below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cancel}

\begin{document}
\sum F_{\perp V}:mV\frac{\text{d}\gamma}{\text{d}t}& =L+T\cancelto{\approx 0}{\sin\alpha_T}-W\cos{\gamma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\cancelto}[3][thick, color=cyan]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
        \node[inner xsep=0pt] (X) at (0,0) {\(\displaystyle #3\)};
        \draw[#1, overlay] (X.south west) -- (X.north) -- (X.north east) node [above left] {\(\scriptstyle #2\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum F_{\perp V}:mV \cancelto{=0}{\frac{\text{d}\gamma}{\text{d}t}} =L+T\cancelto{\approx 0}{\sin\alpha_T}-W\cancelto{=1}{\cos{\gamma}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Since this is different from what `cancel` does, I removed it and defined a new command `\cancelto`.

Comment: Very nice. I like it. :-)

Comment: This is a very nice solution.  It does introduce a bit of extra space due to the size of the node.  Using `inner sep=0pt` and putting `overlay` on the `\draw` avoids that issue.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Good point, thanks for pointing it out! I modified my answer to remove the extra horizontal space.

Comment: Looks good- hadn't thought of only removing the horizontal space but I think it works well.